# What is the process for deciding whether to delete a question versus putting a question 'On Hold'

Tags: discussion

I ask this because I have just noticed a question was deleted by a moderator and it was my first time seeing this. Usually the question would be put 'On Hold' or 'Closed.' Take these two examples:

1. A question marked as "Too Broad" but put 'On Hold': [Implementation of Marketing Cloud from Scratch](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266109/implementation-of-marketing-cloud-from-scratch/266110)
2. A similar question in terms of being "Too Broad" but deleted: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266594/real-time-integration-with-third-party/266601

[image: Deleted answer]

Answer (score 4):

There aren't really hard and fast rules, it's more of a gut feeling about the value of the post. However, a big factor in why I deleted the question you answerd, but not the question Eliot answered, is that your answer was a link-only answer. And while it received some upvotes, it rightfully should have been in the Low Quality Post review queue.

When the question itself is bad, and the answer essentially boils down to RTFM, the whole thread deserves to go. Conversely, Eliot provided some well thought out advice and context in addition to the links he provided. More importantly, I did not even see that thread to consider deleting it.